# Finding out if two Lists have some elements in common by only using map function

Tags: function, maple

I am working on a Problem in Maple. But the question i have is general and could be answered based on ANY programming Language.

The Problem:

- Use only map function (no loops). Assume there are two lists A and B with n and m elements. replace those elements in A with "true", which are also found in B and replace the other elements in A with "false".

The question:
i did try to solve this problem like that:

```
funk := proc(i::integer,j::integer) # checks if two elements are identical
if (i = j) then
return true;
else
return false;
end if;
end proc:

funktion := proc(int::integer, L :: list) # calls funk on every element of L.
map(funk, L, int);
end proc:

SchnittTrueA := proc(M::list, L::list) # calls funktion on every Element of M and L.
map(funktion,M,L);
end proc:
```

And if i run `SchnittTrueA(k,l);` for k :=[1,3] and l := [2,3] i get this result:

```
[[false, false], [false, true]]
```

That is by no mean what i want the Program to do!

i need something like that `[false, true]`

I did try everything i could but i have no idea how to solve this problem.

P.S1: i am a newbie programmer so please do not be hard on me :D.
P.S2: If you want to give me any Tip / Answer, it does not need to be in Maple Language as long as you can use map function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what else you may use, besides `map`. Eg. your user-defined procedure uses `if..then`, etc.

But the following don't use loops.

The first two are reasonably efficient in the sense that for each element `t` in list `A` they generate the `true` as soon as any matching element is found in list `B`.

In contrast the last two approaches are inefficient because they test each element `t` in list `A` against every element in list `B` (even if a match has already been found).

```
restart;
A := [$1..10];

         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

B := [seq(ithprime(i),i=1..4)];

                  [2, 3, 5, 7]

map(member,A,B);

  [false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]

map(t->ormap(evalb@`=`,B,t),A);

  [false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]

map(t->`or`(op(map(evalb@`=`,B,t))),A);

  [false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]

map(t1->`if`(map(t2->`if`(t2=t1,true,NULL),B)=[true],
         true,false),A);

  [false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]
```

Of the four apporaches shown above, the fourth is closest in spirit to your attempt.

I'll show some equivalents to the fourth above, each getting closer to your original attempt.

```
restart;
A := [$1..10]:

B := [seq(ithprime(i),i=1..4)]:
```

Each of these equivalents use those same `A` and `B` example list.

```
func := (t1,t2)->`if`(t2=t1,true,NULL):

funktion := (t1,B)->`if`(map(func,B,t1)=[true],
                     true,false):

map(funktion, A, B);

[false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]
```

Now using `proc` instead of shorter operator syntax.

```
func := proc(t1,t2)
          `if`(t2=t1,true,NULL);
        end proc:

funktion := proc(t1,B)
              `if`(map(func,B,t1)=[true],
                          true,false);
            end proc:

map(funktion, A, B);

[false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]
```

Now using long-form of `if..then`, instead of shorter `if` operator form.

```
func := proc(t1,t2)
          if t2=t1 then
            true;
          else
            NULL;
          end if;
        end proc:

funktion := proc(t1,B)
              if map(func,B,t1)=[true] then
                true;
              else
                false;
              end if;
            end proc:

map(funktion, A, B);

 [false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]
```